# A variation of Minkowski sum

Tags: reference-request, convex-geometry, terminology, additive-combinatorics

I have to work with the following variation of Minkowski sum:

> Let $\mathbb E$ be a Euclidean space and $K$ be a convex set in $\mathbb E\times \mathbb E$.
>   Set 
>   $$K^+=\{\\,x+y\in\mathbb E\mid(x,y)\in K\\,\}.$$

Note that if $K=K_x\times K_y$ for some convex sets  $K_x$ and $K_y$ in $\mathbb E$ then $K^+$ is the usual Minkowski sum of $K_x$ and $K_y$.

**Questions:**

- Did anyone consider this construction?
- Does it have a name?

Comment: Isn't this just a projection of a convex set in $E\times E$
onto a certain quotient space?

Comment: Up to a factor of $\sqrt{2}$, yes.

Comment: @Robin, sure, but I need much more general thing, where  no projections can be defined. 
Mostly I think what would be right way to call such thing...

Comment: @Anton: What kind of more general situation?

Comment: @François, I need some kind of arithmetic in tangent cone of Alexandrov space.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In additive combinatorics, we call the Minkowski sum the sumset, and write it as ${\mathbb E}+{\mathbb E}$. We call what you're talking about the "sumset along a graph", and write it as ${\mathbb E}+_K{\mathbb E}$, where $K$ is any graph (you call it a subset of ${\mathbb E}\times {\mathbb E}$ and I call it a graph, but it's the same thing!).

For an example of this terminology in use, check out [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/0905.0135) of Alon, Angel, Benjamini, and Lubetzky. Also, a [google scholar search](http://www.google.com/search?q=sumsets+along+a+graph) shows the terminology in action.

Comment: Do you have a reference or two? I find this notation rather strange, so I'd like to see it in context.

Comment: @François: I've added a couple of links.

Comment: Thank you, "sumset" sounds nice. By accident it was the first name which I came up with... 